# Mounting an unreachable CIFS results in slow login and other problems

Tags: networking, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I have a NAS that I mount via CIFS. My `/etc/fstab`:

```
//192.168.178.1/FRITZ.NAS/ /home/xxx/NAS cifs credentials=/home\
/xxx/.smbcredentials,vers=3.0,noserverino,uid=1000,\
gid=1000,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.requires=network-online.target,x-systemd.device-timeout=10ms 0 0
```

I works well in my home network, of course, but as soon as I leave the house and 192... isn't available anymore, I experience very slow logins and other problems, i.e. when trying to browse my files with Nautilus or any other program that tries to access the file system.

`dmesg` then shows:

```
[ 1176.653340] CIFS: Attempting to mount //192.168.178.1/FRITZ.NAS/
[ 1186.984727] CIFS: VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[ 1186.984739] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2
[ 1186.993225] CIFS: Attempting to mount //192.168.178.1/FRITZ.NAS/
[ 1197.224579] CIFS: VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[ 1197.224590] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2
[ 1197.233060] CIFS: Attempting to mount //192.168.178.1/FRITZ.NAS/
[ 1207.464505] CIFS: VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[ 1207.464516] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2
[ 1207.476803] CIFS: Attempting to mount //192.168.178.1/FRITZ.NAS/
[ 1217.705176] CIFS: VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[ 1217.705187] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2
[ 1217.713857] CIFS: Attempting to mount //192.168.178.1/FRITZ.NAS/
```

So over the course of dozens of seconds, it tries to mount the NAS again and again, which seems to block the system entirely...

The timeout option I added doesn't seem to help, dmesg tells me it is ignored:

```
[ 1078.414184] systemd-fstab-generator[532]: x-systemd.device-timeout ignored for //192.168.178.1/FRITZ.NAS/
```

Also adding a `nofail` option doesn't help.

Isn't there an option to have a very short timeout so it doesn't bother me when I'm not in my home network?

Comment: Try the _netdev option.

Comment: My mistake, `fg/bg` are options on nfs mounts, so I have deleted comment.

Comment: @vanadium the _netdev option only helps if I'm not logged into another Wifi, i.e. if I'm completely off the grid, it doesn't block login anymore, but with wifi (even though it's not my home wifi), I have the same problems as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on how you use this remote share but I think you have two options:

[1] Keep the systemd.automount but add another option and change your mount point.

You need to add `noauto` to your options and add it before x-systemd.automount.

You will also need to change your mount point to someplace other than in your home directory or under /media. Having it under these locations induces a udisks response that makes the automounter think it's being accessed.

Without these changes your system will always attempt to mount it automatically at boot.

[2] There is another way to do this that doesn't use the systemd automounter and you can keep your mount point:

Replace x-systemd.automount with `noauto,user`

A mount icon will appear on the side panel of your file manager that is actionable. Click on it and it will go to fstab to find out how and mount it with those instructions

Either method will mean the remote share will mount only when accessed and not automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that I still like to have automount when I'm at home. I'm running a backup tool (Duplicati) that needs access to the NAS, and if I always have to mount it manually, that's a bit tedious. Isn't there an option where automount will still work, and if it doesn't, it doesn't block stuff?

Comment: In option [1] you aren't mounting it manually. It is being mounted automatically when the mount point is accessed. That can happen if you access the mount point through your file manager, or is you do an `ls /mountpoint`in a terminal, or if a script or other service accesses that mount point. It is seamless to the user or process.

Comment: Okay. I tried option [2] for now. Turns out that when I click on the network device in Nautilus, a little spinning icon appears and then the NAS is mounted. However, when I access it otherwise (via the file manager by going to the mount point, via the CLI etc.), it's not mounted, so that's what [1] would be good for. But I can imagine that I could use some sort of a setup script before my backup script runs that mounts the volume with the `mount home/xxx/NAS` command, which seems to work without root privileges. So [2] is the option to go for me. Thanks!

Comment: I tested option [2] for a while. Unfortunately, I still have the unresponsive system problems and it tries to automount, so it doesn't really work. Here again is the content of my /etc/fstab: `//192.168.178.1/FRITZ.NAS/ /home/xxx/NAS cifs credentials=/home/xxx/.smbcredentials,vers=1.0,noserverino,uid=1000,gid=1000,noauto,user,x-systemd.requires=network-online.target 0 0`

Comment: I know of no process that would automount the share with noauto in the fstab record unless you have some script that runs at boot by default. If that is the case you should use another systemd option: `x-systemd.mount-timeout=5` "5" is for 5 seconds - use whatever you want. NOTE: This is different from the systemd "device-timeout" operand.

Comment: Okay, I will try this. In the meantime, option [1] works as intended and suits my usecase as well. Thanks!